# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received undefined

Tags: javascript, npm, discord.js

At Object. (C:\Users\Hades\Downloads\Jaxxy\src\bot.js:51:8)

My code for the specified command is

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd'), member => {
  const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel=> channel.name === "welcome");
  if(!channel) return;
  channel.send(`Welcome to Hades's Tavern,$(member), make sure to read the rules in #rules!`)

};
```

I'm on discord.js v12!
Anyone has any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closing parenthesis has to be after the arrow function's body:

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "welcome");
    if (!channel) return;
    channel.send(`Welcome to Hades's Tavern,$(member), make sure to read the rules in #rules!`)

});
```